# Where do modules containing custom functions go in an Express/Node app?

Tags: node.js, express

This question is going to infuriate the most expert people on here, but as a newbie I have a folder structure like this:

- public
- controllers
- views
- models

If I wanted to create a custom "class" (which I guess is a module in Node/Express) with custom functions to format dates, strings etc where exactly does this go? Is there any kind of convention folder to place such classes/modules in or is it just a free-for-all and do what you want?

Comment: This question seems to be opinion-based. There is no well-known convention I know of. For instance, I like to place such classes in the `utils` directory. Or if I have just a couple of helper functions, I place them in the `helpers` directory. Middleware functions go to `middleware` directory. But generally, I don't think there are any conventions that force you to structure your project in a certain way. Just keep it clear - that should be the main goal.

Comment: Would a custom formatter removing HTML tags from a string be middleware, helper, or util?

Comment: I would say it's a util if it's a class with more complicated logic. But if it's just a simple function I would make it a helper

Answer (score 1):

There is no official folder convention for express.js, but there is a very commonly used convention, which you can find [here](https://github.com/anandundavia/express-api-structure).

Depending on your general project structure it would probably be `api/controllers`.

Comment: appreciate the answer Florian but its not a controller. Its like User-Defined Functions to do date formatting (short and long), removing HTML tags from strings that kind of stuff. It could be middleware because it helps out before sending the response back to the client.

Comment: If your user object is from a database you could also put it into repository. In this case you might put your functions not into the object. However if none of the descriptions match your use case it might be the best to just create a new folder before using a wrong one.